microsoft onedrive embed works and gives bunch of content security errors
I'm trying to insert onedrive video embed in blogs/news articles from editor (@kolkov/angular-editor). it works, but throws too mush errors like one in photo. I researched and read that it's content security policy, but can't find how to fix it.
note that I already tried using this safe pipe
here is code snippet:
insertVideoURL() {
    const urlOrEmbed = prompt("Please enter the video URL or iframe embed code:");
  
    if (urlOrEmbed) {
      try {
        let content = '';
        try {
          // working on youtube urls
        } catch (error) {
          if (/^<iframe[^>]*src="https:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.sharepoint\.com[^"]+"[^>]*><\/iframe>$/.test(urlOrEmbed)) {
            content = urlOrEmbed;
          } else {
            throw new Error('Only YouTube URLs and OneDrive iframe embeds are supported.');
          }
        }
  
        const currentContent = this.form.get('description')?.value || '';
        const updatedContent = currentContent + content;
        this.form.get('description')?.setValue(updatedContent);
      } catch (error) {
        // console.log(error.message);
        alert(`Error: ${error.message}`);
      }
    } else {
      console.log("No URL or embed code provided.");
    }
  }


